# Tensorflow test fails

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm testing TF and when I test for addition I get:

```
E       AssertionError: 
E       Arrays are not equal
E       
E       (mismatch 100.0%)
E        x: array(4.099999904632568, dtype=float32)
E        y: array(4.1)
```

If I change test from 3.1 to 3.0, it works? Any suggestions

**Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import unittest

def sum_op(param1, param2):
    return tf.add(param1, param2)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    result = sum_op(tf.constant(1.0), tf.Variable(2.0))
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        print sess.run(result)



class AddTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    def testAdd(self):
        with self.test_session() as sess:
            self.assertAllEqual(sum_op(1.0, 3.1).eval(), 4.1)


suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(AddTest)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, testing for exact equality with floating point arithmetic is prone to errors. You may want to read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

You should use a tolerance when checking floating point code, such as numpy's `isclose` [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html).

Comment: I used assertAlmostEqual and delta option